# week number of the year, kinda

Tags: ruby, date, time

Preferably in ruby, but the logic would be good enough...

I need the week number of the year given that the week is non-standard.  So, say you define a week as Saturday -> Friday.  Then, given a date, which week number (1-52) is it?

strftime has %U:

```
> Time.now.strftime('%U')
> => "28"
```

...but that of course assumes a standard Sunday -> Saturday week.

Comment: maybe use this standard and then calculate your own offset based on todays day of week...

Comment: Sunday -> Saturday is only American standard. International standard is Monday -> Sunday.

Answer (score 36):

Use `%W` instead of `%U`, it uses Monday as the first day of the week.

```
Time.now.strftime('%W')
```

Comment: But it's zero indexed, as opposed to `Date.today.cweek` form @fl00r's answer.

Answer (score 22):

```
class Date
  def sweek
    date = self + 1
    date.cweek
  end
end

# Today is Sunday, 17 July
Date.today.cweek
#=> 28
Date.today.sweek
#=> 29
```

Comment: nice, but +0 for monkey patching a core class, btw strangely `Time.new.strftime('%W') != Time.new.to_date.cweek`

Comment: @akostadinov: You probably got this long ago now, but for posterity, `Time.new.strftime('%W')` returns a String while `Time.new.to_date.cweek` returns an Integer, so they're not expected to be equal.

Comment: Instead of patching things that are already solved, just read the docs and find the present solution. See Thiago's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe can do like this;

```
def week_dates( week_num )
    year = Time.now.year
    week_start = Date.commercial( year, week_num, 1 )
    week_end = Date.commercial( year, week_num, 7 )
    week_start.strftime( "%m/%d/%y" ) + ' - ' + week_end.strftime( 
"%m/%d/%y" )
  end
```

Comment: Looking for the week number of a given date.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a [ISO week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) use %V according [strftime documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Example:

```
require 'date'

puts DateTime.parse('2018-12-30 23:59:59').strftime('%G-%V')
puts DateTime.parse('2018-12-31 00:00:00').strftime('%G-%V')
```

Result:

```
2018-52
2019-01
```

Note that it was used %G for year and not %Y.

Answer (score 1):

We can figure out how to shift the week number from what's returned by `%U` (Sun starts the week) by considering this calendar fragment:

`August 2015
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1  %U => 30
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  %U => 31
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  %U => 32`

Let's way we want a Wed-Tue week, abbreviated as format `%?` (so we don't have to type out "Wed starts week").

We want:

`August 2015
We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu 
          1  2  3  4  %? => 30
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11  %? => 31
12 13 14 15           %? => 32`

Notice how We-Sa stay in the same week number in both systems, while all other days of the week are moved to the previous week in `%?`.

So we can do this:

```
startd = Date.new(2015, 8, 1)
# show whole month
pp (startd .. (startd >> 1)-1).map {|d|
  origw = d.strftime('%U').to_i
  # Adjust our new week number if not We-Sa:
  neww = ([3, 4, 5, 6].include?(d.wday) ? origw : origw-1)
  [d.to_s, origw, neww]
}
```

If you wanted Sat-Fri week, you can subtract 1 for days that aren't Saturday:

```
d.wday == 6 ? origw : origw-1
```

Note that there are a couple edge cases, depending on what you choose your week to be (handling these is left as an exercise for the reader). For our Wed-Tue week:

- Year 2014 starts with Wed, but our algorithm puts Jan 1 in week 0 but it should be week 1 (`%U` puts Jan 1 in week 1 if it's Sunday).
- Year 2007 (and other years that start on Mon or Tue) will cause the days before the first Wed to be in week -1 but they should be week 0.

The more days of the week you're adjusting, the more edge cases you'll have. Sat-Fri week will probably have the most problems because you're adjusting 6 out of 7 days.